# Callisto multiple reference errors

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, callisto

Recently I tried to install callisto 1.1.0 and 1.2.6 for a windows store application. But after installation my application stopped running and popped out this error

> Error 1   An assembly with the same simple name 'Callisto,
>   Version=1.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null has already been
>   imported. Try removing one of the references or sign them to enable
>   side-by-side. c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\Callisto\1.2.6\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral\Callisto.dll    Callisto_AppBar

I tried removing the dll files from the installed location and reinstalling the latest version of callisto. But still the same error is popping up. It would be great if someone could share a solution for it.

Comment: I think you have installed Callisto as extension SDK. I recommend you to install via [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/callisto). It works fine as NuGet install libraries with project only scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple versions of this library in your project...only one is permitted.