# 64bit targeted Metro style app using C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, 64-bit

Metro style app 32bit / 64bit

I deployed a metro style app written in C#/xaml with target framework x64
 [image: Target Framework], but it shows up in task manager as 32-bit. 
[image: Task Manager]

Can any one tell what went wrong or what i am missing ?

Comment: Why does your Metro app require more than 3GB of memory?

Comment: What is your reason for wanting a 64-bit app?

Comment: @leppie: does it matter? It could be the improved ASLR, it could be that he *does* do something memory-intensive, it could be that he just wants to be able to make a 64-bit app. And it could be that the *next* person to find this question will need to use more tha 3GB, so why don't we just assume that our processors are 64-bit for a reason, and that some people might just want to *use* that capability.

Comment: Do you have any underlying 32-bit DLL's or are all your references X64 builds?

Comment: @jordanhill123 i am referring to Callisto controls , but that doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: Callisto controls appear to be an x86 build per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661041/callisto-multiple-reference-errors but I don't know enough to know if this will cause it.

Comment: Check your debug configuration

Answer (score 1):

I compile and run my in development applications to "Any CPU" and it runs on x86 and x86-64, showing properly in the task manager.

Try to isolate you project to see if it's any library or dependency that's causing that. failing that, forcing it to run only as x64 should provide clues.

Answer (score 0):

In "Build --> Configuration Manager" menu, check your "Active Solution Platform" selection.

I guess you selected "x86" instead of "Any CPU" (the default setting) or "x64" (which is your desired target platform right?).